# Who is Lord of Hades?

Tags: cage-of-eden

This guy:

[image: Hades]

He's wearing same uniform with other student. His first appearance is when He knocked Akira down with a rock. He saw Kouhei Arita stabbed Masaru Tsuchiya (Pilot) in the chest. But [his identity was never revealed](http://cageofeden.wikia.com/wiki/Hades), there are also several [interesting theories about him](http://edennoori.wikia.com/wiki/Hades). Who is this guy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question where we will mostly likely never get a proper answer on.

> the publishers no longer liked cage of eden so the author was forced
>   to rush everything. Therefore leaving a bunch a plot holes and having
>   to come up with a conclusion as fast as possible. [source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/2000121-anime-and-manga-other-titles/65225551?page=2)
>
> It probably has a rushed ending because the manga may have lost the
>   required ranking to keep being published, which means they more than
>   likely only gave for a few more releases to wrap the series up. [source](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=39089)

Due to not making enough sales the manga has had a rushed ending forcing the writer to close it up as soon as posible. There for leaving indeed a bunch of plot holes and unused potentionals such as hades.

Comment: It sucks that this series was cancelled.

Comment: @krikara i think we all agree on that.